# How do I give arguments to a function that accepts function pointer

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I am trying to do something like this:

```
void print (int number)
{
    printf("Argument \"%i\" has been given", number);
}

void foo (void (*ptr)(int arg))
{
    ptr(arg);
}

int main (void)
{
    foo(print(10));

    return 0;
}
```

Unlikely this will work, because `print(10)` should return void, not an actual function address.. but at least I hope my question is understandable as it is very hard for me to explain it with plain words.

---

How do I transfer arguments in a function pointer like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "transfer arguments in a function pointer like that". What you can do instead is pass an additional argument that match the argument expected by your function pointer.

This would looks like this:

```
void print (int number)
{
    printf("Argument \"%i\" has been given", number);
}

void foo (void (*ptr)(int), int arg) // the new argument is here.
{
    ptr(arg);
}

int main (void)
{
    foo(print, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

### Alternative

What we are doing here is packing the argument and the function pointer together in a struct, and passing this struct to `foo()`.
This is a bit similar to c++'s [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) but simplified and less powerful.

```
typedef struct bind_s
{
  void (*ptr)(int);
  int arg;
} bind_t;

void print (int number)
{
  printf("Argument \"%i\" has been given", number);
}

void foo (bind_t call)
{
  call.ptr(call.arg);
}

int main (void)
{
  bind_t call = {print, 10};
  foo(call);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I did on a first place. I was hoping for another solution to this, because it looked like I lack of knowledge instead. I think this can be accomplished with heavy macros though.

Comment: This seems like a clean and simple solution to the actual problem. If it works for you should use it. In case you are familiar with c++, std::bind would pick your interest. What did you hoped for ?

Comment: At least some sort of an evil macro instead of function pointer argument and initialization.

Comment: Yes what you want to do seems similar to `std::bind` in c++. You *could* achieve this by using `struct` to hold function pointer + argument.